# JQuery FormData Get/Post

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

Im tring to post FormData values to controller. Its success on POST method but i want to get returned values. I tried get but dont work. I added too many argument but dont work. Can u help me ?

jquery/ajax

```
var Data = new FormData();
        Data.append('yparca', yparca);
        Data.append('mekanik', mekanik);
        //more values
        $.each($("#img_upload_" + id)[0].files, function (i, file) {
            Data.append('resimler', file);
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Sections/AddRowsToMarketPart",
            type: 'GET',
            data: Data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType:'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success");
                
                Toast.fire({
                    icon: 'success',
                    title: 'Parça sepete eklendi.'
                })
            }
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult AddRowsToMarketPart(SubPart2Val model)
        {
           //Do something AND RETURN A VALUE
           return Json(model);
        }
```

Class

```
 public class SubPart2Val
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string yparca { get; set; }
        public string mekanik { get; set; }
        //some properties

        public List<IFormFile> resimler { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: oky. sorry for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content type is incorrect, you set it as json when it's form data.
To have it set properly in $.ajax set `contenType` to false
Also you cant sent form data with a GET request use POST

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Sections/AddRowsToMarketPart",
    type: 'POST',
    data: Data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType:'json',
    ...

[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AddRowsToMarketPart(SubPart2Val model)
        {
           //Do something AND RETURN A VALUE
           return Json(model);
        }
```

Comment: when i put "GET" tag to type , my model filling with null.

Comment: controller works but success doesn't work.

Comment: i fixed. ty so much.